# Regex for extracting text from .eml file

Tags: regex, sharepoint-2013, phrase, nintex-workflow

I need to write regex to get the following data from an email. The data to be phrased is first name, last name, phone number, email id, pin code, message etc, i am a newbie and am not much aware of REGEX, can anyone help me with it.

`enter code here`Contact Us

Title

Mr.

Last Name

S

First Name

Nitesh

Contact Us

By phone on:
0344 892 8979

E-Mail Address

niteshdsingh@gmail.com<mailto:niteshdsingh@gmail.com>

Phone Number

123456789

Postcode

421202

City

test

Message

test

Best Regards,

Comment: Please edit your question and remove your company name. Other wise we will downvote your question and flag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this regex can be regarded as a generic email parser... rather it will only work for the format that you have provided:

```
Last\s+Name(?:\n)+((?: *\w+)+)|First\s+Name(?:\n)+((?: *\w+)+)|By phone on:((?: *\d+)+)|(?:E-Mail\s+Address(?:\n)+((?:(?: *\w+)+)@[^\.]+\.[^<]+))|(?:Phone Number(?:\n)+((?: *\w+)+))|(?:Postcode(?:\n)+((?: *\w+)+))|(?:Message(?:\n)+((?: *\w+)+))
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HPYaIt/1/)

Here in the following groups you get your desired data:

```
Group 1.    Last Name
Group 2.    First Name
Group 3.    By phone on
Group 4.    email
Group 5.    Phone Number
Group 6.    Postcode
Group 7.    Message
```

> UPDATED AS PER THE OP COMMENT:

```
(?:E-Mail\s+Address(?:\n)+((?:(?: *\w+)+)@[^\.]+\.[^<]+))|(?:Phone Number(?:\n)+((?: *\w+)+))|(?:Postcode(?:\n)+((?: *\w+)+))|(?:Message(?:\n)+((?: *\w+)+))|(?:City(?:\n)+((?: *\w+)+))
```

[Demo Two](https://regex101.com/r/HPYaIt/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rizwan, how can I extract email id,city and how to avoid the last name,first name,by phone no. extension.

Comment: email is already provided in this answer ... Here for data there is a pipe | that separates the regex, you can remove the part that you dont want from it

Comment: Anyway, I have updated the answer for your convenience.. have a look and also see **Demo Two** for details